# Relation $S(2x)=2S(x)-9N(x)$.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Let $S(x)$ be the sum of digits of number $x$ and $N(x)$ be the number of digits of $x$  greater than $4$. Prove that $S(2x)=2S(x)-9N(x)$.

For example, if $x=1992$ then $S(x)=1+9+9+2=21$ and $S(2x)=3+9+8+4=24$ and $N(x)=1+1=2$. Hence $24=2\times 21-9\times 2$.

Can anyone show its full solution? Unfortunately I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Let $l(x)$ be the length of the decimal representation of $x$. Use induction on $l(x)$. Suppose the identity holds for $l(x)\le n$.

Let $x=10y+r$ where $l(y)=n$ and $r\in\{0,1,\cdots,9\}$. $S(10z)=z\;\forall\;z$.

> If $r<5\implies N(x)=N(y)$

$$
S(2x)=S(20y+2r)=S(20y)+2r=S(2y)+2r\\
=2S(y)-9N(y)+2r=2S(10y)-9N(x)+2r\\
=2S(10y+r)-9N(x)=2S(x)-9N(x)
$$

> If $r\ge5\implies N(x)=N(y)+1$

$$
S(2x)=S(20y+2r)=S(20y)+2r-9=S(2y)+2r-9\\
=2S(y)-9N(y)+2r-9=2S(10y)+2r-9N(x)\\
=2S(10y+r)-9N(x)=2S(x)-9N(x)
$$

Comment: 1) If $x=\overline{a_n\dots a_1a_0}$ then $l(x)=n+1$. Am I right? 2) So you suggest induction for $l(x)$. What is the base in this case? 3) Why $S(10z)=z$? These moments seems little complicated.

Comment: $1)$ You're right. $2)$ For base case $l(x)=1$ or $x=0,1,\cdots, 9$. You only have $10$ cases. If $x<5$, $N(x)=0$ so. $S(2x)=2x=2S(x)-9N(x)$. If $x\ge5$, $N(x)=1$ so $S(2x)=2x-9=2S(x)-9N(x)$. $(3)$ Just look at an example. $z=1336\implies 10z=13360$ so you only have to add an extra zero.

Comment: $S(1336)=1+3+3+6+0=S(13360)$

Comment: Excellent! I will continue to watch the solution

Comment: If $9\ge r\ge 5$, $r=5+k\implies 2r=10+2k$. As $k\le 4, 2k\le 8$. Let $2k=p$, the decimal representation of $2r$ looks like $1p$. So $S(2x)=1+p=1+2k=1+2r-10=2r-9$.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that the number of digits greater than $4$ is $N(x)$, we can look at $S(2x)$. Let the number of digits of $x$ be $n$. Then the number of digits less than or equal to $4$ is $n-N(x)$, and those digits multiplied by $2$ are less than $10$, so the sum of these digits of $2x$ is simply twice the sum of these digits of $x$. If a digit is greater than $4$, then what happens with the sum of the digits when we multiply by $2$? We see that, given a digit $d>4$, we know that, when we sum the digits of $2x$, the digit $2d$ (which is not actually a single digit, but that's not a problem since we compute the sum of the two digits that result from $2d$) is $2d-10$ for the last digit and $1$ for the first, so the sum is $2d-9$. Thus, since there are $N(x)$ such digits $d$, we have $$S(2x)=2S(x)-9N(x)$$

I realize that my arguments may a bit vague to some people, so if you're having trouble understanding my answer, leave a comment with what part you find difficult to understand, and I'll be very glad to edit my answer so that it may be clearer.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Can upu explain that moment: "we know that the "sum of that digit" when looking at $2x$ (so the sum of the digits of $2d$) is $(2d−10)$ for the last digit and $1$ for the first, so the sum is $2d−9$". What means "sum of that digit?"

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I was unclear. I edited my answer, but will still do an example to illustrate the argument I'm trying to show. In case of $x=1992$, we take any digit $d>4$, so $d=9$. Now if we look at the sum of the digits of $2x$ (the idea is to do this digit by digit, knowing the digits of $x$), then we can sum the digits of $2d$ separately (that is $1+8=9=2d-9$).